# Is there a way to install a package from source directory so that it may be worked on whilst still being able to import namesspace

Tags: r

e.g. Python has a `pip install --editable` which symlinks the source directory into the package directory so you can hack on the code whilst still making it available in the package namespace.

The closest i have found is `R.utils::sourceDirectory` but this has no namespacing.

Thanks

Comment: You'll need to reinstall the package after any change to make the changes available to your R session. However, this is actually not much of an impediment; make changes -> `devtools::install("path/to/my_package")` -> use the changes

Comment: Can you please be more specific on the intended usage? Then we can perhaps answer better.

Comment: Not sure whether this is what you are looking for, but using automated testing (see for example http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/tests.html) and 'devtools::test()' can provide a nice workflow. Independent of the tests you specify you can use it to "update" changes you make to the source code.